# Epsilon/Delta Proof from Definition of Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How would you go about proving that:

$\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{1}{x-2}= -\infty$
(i.e. x approaching 2 from left hand side)

Been struggling to make much headway on this. Not sure how I'm supposed to use Epsilon in this case. So far, I have: 
Given any negative number M there exists $\delta$ s.t. $f(x) < M$ if $0<|x-2|<\delta$ 
-> $\frac{1}{x-2} < M$ if "..." 
-> $\frac{1}{M} > x-2$ if "..."

Really not sure how to proceed from here. Can't find any online examples like it and the one in my book is for $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (I understand it, but not sure how to apply it here).

Any help/feedback/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M<0$ given.

we look for $\delta$ such that

if

$\color{red}{0<2-x<\delta}$ then

$\frac{1}{x-2}<M<0$

or

$\frac{1}{2-x}>-M>0$

which becomes after inversion

$\color{red}{0<2-x<-\frac{1}{M}}$

so we can take

$\delta=-\frac{1}{M}$ .

Answer (score 0):

Assume  $2-\frac 1 n <x < 2$. Then $-\frac  1 n < x-2 < 0$ and hence $\frac 1 {x-2} < - \frac 1 {1/n} = - n$.

Comment: Sorry if it seems stupid, but could you explain the thought process behind this. I think I'm just missing something

Comment: $n$ is large so $1/n$ is small so $x$ is between a number slightly less than $2$ and $2$. Then we subtract $2$ throughout and take reciprocals (thus reversing the order) with the result that your term is less than any negative number.